# Is there a way to match bytes at a variable offset in a packet using nftables?

Tags: linux, nftables, netfilter

The iptables `xt_bpf` extension can be used to access auxiliary packet data, such as payload length. The `xt_u32` extension can do it to some extent as well. I know that nftables supports a length meta selector, but the [raw payload expression](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/nftables/nft.8.en.html#RAW_PAYLOAD_EXPRESSION) only supports fixed offsets or the base of layer 2, 3, or 4 headers. Is there any way to perform a match at a variable offset, for example to match SNI, using only nftables? As this is an embedded system with extremely limited resources, it isn't ideal to use both nftables and iptables simultaneously.

I would rather not use `libnetfilter_queue` or anything else which passes the decision making to userland, if possible. The filtering should occur entirely within the kernel.

Comment: You can use iptables, which has such feature, along nftables lacking the feature, and have them communicate using a mark. See [When and how to use chain priorities in nftables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419851/when-and-how-to-use-chain-priorities-in-nftables/), [How --set-mark option works on Netfilter (IPTABLES)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467076/how-set-mark-option-works-on-netfilter-iptables) and as an example of such cooperation [nftables whitelisting docker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657545/nftables-whitelisting-docker).

Comment: @A.B I'd rather keep the entirety of iptables out of the kernel.

Comment: That means you'd rather not have the feature...

Comment: @A.B If there's no way at all to do this without `libnetfilter_queue` or creating my own module, then please write that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It's too difficult to say "no" for sure as an answer. That's why I was talking about alternatives. Are you in a constrained (embedded) environment to not even want some kernel modules and create your own instead?

Comment: @A.B That's correct. The kernel is custom configured, so it's not just a matter of not wanting to use the `iptables` commands. Do you suggest I add that detail to my question to improve it?